# Use naive bayes for numerical attributes

Tags: machine-learning, naivebayes

Can we use naive bayes for classification of numerical data.  We have a system which extract authors styles such as sentence length,word length and use it to predict authorship of anonymous documents. So can we use naive bayes to classify authors based on these numerical data. Else can you suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. In fact, every learning algorithm that I'm aware of works with numerical features: when dealing with other kind of data you have to preprocess it to numerical data first.

I would suggest you also look into [Support Vector Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), [Online Passive Aggressive Classifiers](http://webee.technion.ac.il/people/koby/publications/crammer06a.pdf) and [TF-IDF weighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) for this task.

Comment: Can you suggest some python packages where I can work with numeric attributes with naive bayes

Comment: @Nithin.P - I like scikit-learn the most. It has everything I mentioned and also Naive Bayes. Have a look at its SGDClassifier too. And this tutorial for working with text data: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Comment: Thank you! SK-Learn is perfect for me.

Comment: @Nithin.P - if you found my answer helpful, please accept it by clicking the tick mark next to it.